# Validate 5 Combo Boxes is Not choose Same Value

Tags: php, android-studio

I need to ask how to validate Each combo box is not select same value
ex : 
Filter by :

> - [Combobox] [TextBox] And
> - [Combobox] [TextBox] And
> - [Combobox] [TextBox] And
> - [Combobox] [TextBox] And
> - [Combobox] [TextBox]

We have five combobox And value for each Combobox is

- Name
- Job
- Age
- City
- Place

What I want to Achieve is If Combobox 1 and 3 Choose Name its Said that "Can't choose 2 Filter type"

Comment: what have you tried? this platform is not a free source code provider

Comment: what I already tried is Using "if", I'm sorry I'm new in this world still learning simple